# when i write options of the selectbox from different php page with jquery,it fails!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hi i am  developing a web app.I am retrieving options of the select box from database and i want to write these records to selectbox.My page structure is like that:

main.php=>there is a selectbox in this page   `<select id="my_select"></select>`

retrieve_data.php=>i make a ajax call to this page and this page gets the phone numbers from the db and responses the data to main.php.

i get the data from the retrieve_data.php but when  wanted to write these response to selectbox it fails.only empty selectbox appears.

My response like his:`<option>blabla</option>`......

and i wrote it like this: `$("#my_select").html(response);`

i alerted the response before writing in to selectbox and it alerts right options but when i tried to write them into selectbox it fails.can anyone help me thanks for advance...

Comment: Can you please verify that the response is a String and not (for example) an Array?

Comment: Have you inspected the json response in Firebug? You should get a better idea of your response structure there. Or for your alert, try this: `alert(typeof JSON.data.response);`

Comment: i did what you said and my response is a string.

Comment: Should work. If you do `$("#my_select").html('<option>blabla</option>');`, does it work? Does `JSON.data.response` contain anything other than the `<option>` tags?

Comment: yes if i write $("#my_select").html('<option>blabla</option>'); by hand it works.However when  get it from other page it doesnt work.I copy the response and i wrote it to the $("#my_select").html('here'); and it works.I think the problem is about encoding or escape characters in the option tags

Comment: when i replace the html with text  like that $("#my_select").text('<option>blabla</option>'); it prints only the text version of the selectbox and options.Here is the output
<otpion value="00905547811669">00905547811669</option>
<otpion value="00905547811665">00905547811665</option>
<otpion value="00905547811664">00905547811664</option> 
<otpion value="00902124141234">00902124141234</option>

Comment: I noticed that your opening `<option>` tags from the output are mis-spelled `<otpion>`. Is that the actual output, or did that occur when posting here?

Comment: thank you very much :D i have been trying for ours to do that....I will be out of my mind.thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer with the correct solution for the record. If you check the checkmark next to that answer, it will verify that it was the proper solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that the `response` is coming back in the form of a single member array. That would explain why the `alert()` shows the response, but it is not being inserted.

So, try this:

```
$("#my_select").html( response.join('') );
```

**EDIT:**

`<option>` tags in output were misspelled.

Comment: hi patrick my response type is JSON and i used your code :$("#my_select").html((JSON.data.resonse).join(''));   but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery `.html()` function *is* correct, but I need to see more code to understand your problem.  Particularly what is `response` equal to? It looks like, as others have mentioned, that the `response` variable is coming back as JSON rather than a simple string. Can you post what it looks like when you do an `alert(response);`?

Comment: function get_setting_numbers(type){
    var type=type;
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions/get_setting_numbers.php',
            data:'type='+type,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(JSON){
     if(JSON.data.result=="true"){
        alert(JSON.data.response);
                 $("#first_rule").html(JSON.data.response);                
                }else{
                open_message(JSON.data.response,0);
                
          }
         }
        });
    
}

Comment: you should post additional content relative to your question in the body of the question itself. with proper spacing, etc... to make it readable to those trying to help you. just edit the question and add the new content.

Answer (score 0):

Could be [this bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228) if you are using Explorer.